# I am trying to implement in my Dataset LIKE but it isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

```
SELECT        sifra, Naslov, Avtor, Lokacija, Broj, Zabeleska, Izdava
FROM            [Table]
WHERE        (Naslov LIKE @Naslov)
```

here is what i have and when i use = (when i write full word) it works ok but when i want to use a part of the word with LIKE it's not working

Comment: How should i use it for an INT ????

Comment: (Broj LIKE CAST(@Broj AS varchar(10)) + '%')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `%+ @naslov+%` before you use `like`.